# Trace-preserving low-rank symmetric matrix approximation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank, trace

I have a symmetric $n\times n$ matrix $H$ and I want to make a $k$-rank approximation that preserves the trace. In symbols:

$$ H \approx J D J^\top, \quad \operatorname{Tr}(H) = \operatorname{Tr}(J D J^\top),$$

where $D$ is $k\times k$ diagonal and $J$ is $n\times k$.

My current idea is: I take the largest magnitude eigenvalue *with the same sign of the trace* and put it in $D_{11}$, and $J_1$ is the corresponding normalized eigenvector. Then I remove this eigenspace from the matrix: $H' = H - D_{11}J_1J_1^\top$, and repeat recursively on $H'$ until I have picked $k$ eigenspaces. Finally, I rescale $D$ so that $\operatorname{Tr}(D) = \operatorname{Tr}(H)$.

This is similar to the usual non-trace-preserving SVD cut, but it is different. Example: $k=1$, the largest magnitude eigenvalue is positive, but the trace is negative, so the minimum eigenvalue is picked instead.

In my problem the sign of eigenvalues matters so I do it this way to make sure the sign of eigenvalues is not flipped to preserve the trace.

Also, this can be implemented in $O(n^2 k)$ as the usual cut.

Does anyone know something about this kind of approximation? Is it something already studied? I could not find it.

(My problem is computing second order propagation of moments. $H$ is the hessian and for a moment of order $m$ the computation is $O(n^m)$ with full rank, and $O(n k^m)$ with rank $k$. The trace is the first order moment.)

Comment: Have you tried your approach on the matrix $H = \pmatrix{2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1}$, aiming for a rank-1 approximation? Sometimes a 1D or 2D or 3D example can lead to considerable insight. Also: what metric are you using to determine the quality of the approximation?

Comment: Yes I have thought about what happens with 2D matrices. The metric: I don't even know what the appropriate metric would be. If I could express my algorithm as minimization of a metric I could better understand what it's doing at least, then think if another metric is better but still yields $O(n^2k)$. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: If you don't have a way of measuring the quality of the solution (i.e., a preferred metric), then there's no "correct" answer to your question. Maybe "What's the metric I should be using here?" is the question that really needs answering; I suspect the answer has something to do with the underlying motivation of the question (i.e., moments), so you want to think about your matrix as representing a quadratic form rather than representing a linear transformation. But that's just me making wild guesses.

Comment: Just to drive home the point about the metric, here's an essentially instant answer: pick $J$ to be a diagonal matrix with $1$s on the diagonal, and $D = diag(t/k,t/k, t/k,\ldots, t/k, 0, 0, \ldots 0)$, where there are $k$ copies of $t/k$, and $t$ is the trace of $H$. The result is a rank-$k$ (very bad) approximation with the right trace.